# Help with Select?

Tags: c, sockets, select, file-descriptor

So i'm trying to make a server that listens on multiple ports.
I'm having trouble getting my head around select.

Could someone give me a little bit of pseudo code around the order I do things and why.

I get that i bind two separate sockets to different ports. Sure. But then can I just call listen on both ports?

On my client(s), do i just call connect, and listen will notice the connection attempt? How do i choose to accept it?

Sorry for the novice questions. I've tried beejs guide and a few others, but they don't really cover multiple ports very well (they all seem to use the same example).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After calling `bind` and `listen` on the server, the fd for the socket is just another fd that you can use with the `select` call.  When `select` returns and indicates data on that fd, you can call `accept` on the fd to begin receiving data.

Edit: Also, the fd you receive when you `accept` the connection is another fd that can be passed to the `select` call.

Comment: So on my select, i have 2 possible sockets. When select returns, how do I know which socket it returned because of?

Comment: @Blackbinary - It can return because of either or both (or none but lets leave that for another day).  Select will return how many sockets (file descriptors) are ready.  You loop through calling FD_ISSET().  This will return true if that descriptor is ready and you call accept() on it.  It is up to *you* to keep track of what the FDs are.

Comment: Okay, so on my loop i ask FD_ISSET(FD_1), and if thats true, i do whatever I need to for the first connection. If FD_ISSET(FD_2) is true, then i know there is data for the second connection

Comment: @Blackbinary - That's correct.  But for flexibility you will eventually want to put the FDs into lists so you don't have to hard code each one.  The list should also contain information if it is a listening socket (you'll want to call accept()) or a connected socket (call read or write or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Client Side:
you need only to call the connect.

Server side the steps are more or less the following:

1. create the socket
2. Bind the socket
3. Start listening
4. Add file descriptor of the listening socket to the select
5. When the select return on the listening socket then call the accept function upon it. It will return another file descriptor(remember to add this new file descriptor to the list of the FD for which the select has to return through FD_SET)

Comment: so when you say 'start listening', that means I can make more than one listen calls? like I could say `listen(sock1,QUEUE_SIZE)` and `listen(sock2,QUEUE_SIZE)` and they dont get in each others way?

Comment: @Blackbinary: no.you can make one one call on the listening socket

Comment: @0verbose - he means two separate listening sockets.  @Blackbinary - yes you can make a listen call on the two separate sockets.  You should make them non-blocking before any of this takes place though.

Comment: @Duck: thanks for pointing out. I misunderstood Blackbinary's question

Comment: What do i have to do special to make these listens non-blocking?

Comment: @Blackbinary - fcntl().  See http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/fcntlman.html